# Unable to display recyclerview contents in fragment class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerview inside a class which extends Fragment. But nothing gets displayed. I am calling recyclerview inside StringRequest onResponse function inside the class. Below are my codes. Can anyone please help me in solving this.

The constructor for ChatMessageGroups gets called, however onCreateViewHolder() & onBindViewHolder() are not. The getItemCount() also return more than 0.

ChatGroups.java

```
public class ChatGroups extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chat_groups, container, false);

        final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(view.getContext());
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_chat_groups);
                            ChatMessageGroups mAdapter = new ChatMessageGroups(jsonResponse.getString("groups"));

                            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
                            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected HashMap<String, String> getParams() {
                HashMap<String, String> details = new HashMap<String, String>();
                details.put("key", session.getKey());
                return details;
            }
        };
        queue.add(strReq);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chat_groups, container, false);
    }
}
```

ChatMessageGroups.java

```
public class ChatMessageGroups extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatMessageGroups.MyViewHolder> {

    private final JSONArray messages;

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView group_name;

        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
        group_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.group_name);

        }
    }

    ChatMessageGroups(JSONArray messages) {
        this.messages = messages;

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_chat_groups_list, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        try
        {
            HashMap<String, String> maps = (HashMap<String, String>) messages.get(position);
            for(HashMap.Entry<String, String> v: maps.entrySet())
            {
                String key = String.valueOf(v.getKey());
                String value = String.valueOf(v.getValue());

holder.group_name.setText(value);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.length();
    }
}
```

activity_chat_groups_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/group_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_chat_groups.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_chat_groups"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it...

Changed return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chat_groups, container, false); to return view;

It started working.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to display recyclerview contents in fragment class

In your `onBindViewHolder`, nothing set to display. That's why you don't see anything.

Comment: If I try to print anything inside onBindViewHolder, nothing gets printed.

Comment: try calling adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(), after setting adapter to recyclerview

Comment: does your onBindViewHolder and onCreateViewHolder get called?

Comment: No.. they are not getting called. If I write System.out.println inside these functions, they are not printing. But inside constructor it is printing.

Comment: if you have non zero size list then, onBindViewHolder must get called after you call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_chat_groups);
                                ChatMessageGroups mAdapter = new ChatMessageGroups(groups);
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
                                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

Comment: Have you tried defining the RecyclerView as a member variable?

Comment: Where is view defined here? ChatMessageGroups(JSONArray messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
        group_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.group_name);

    }

Comment: If the item not appearing is activity_chag_group_list, the textview  has visibility:"gone"

Comment: I have removed the visibility, but still it is not coming.. The methods onCreateViewHolder() and onBindViewHolder() are itself not getting called..

Answer (score 0):

In your first code, there is a:

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST
```

Instead POST, it should be GET?

Comment: Did you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Make the message variable static in the adapter class.

Comment: Which variable please ?

Comment: private final JSONArray messages; this one in ChatMessageGroups.

Comment: Check for null in ChatMessageGroups method and try to show a toast, also try to make the method public.

Comment: It is not null.. If I print the size of messages, it is showing as 1...

Comment: Hmm I suspect it's an adapter problem.

Comment: Any Solution please ? Or how to debug more ?

Comment: I am getting this error "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout" in logcat.. any help ?

Comment: I recommend reading guides about recyclerview.
No adapter attached can have many casues.
onBindViewHolder try to check it against null.

Comment: Great that you finally got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do something different:

Initialize the `RecyclerView`, `Adapter`, `LayoutManager` etc in the body of `onCreateView`.

Make the RecyclerView and the Adapter member variables in that way you will be able to reference the adapter from the listener with no warnings about it not being final...

When you create the adapter pass it an empty `JSONArray`.

So all the initialization calls gest done in `onCrateView()`.

Second add, a method

```
public void changeMessages(JSONArray messages){
    this.messages = messages;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

to your adapeter.

Finally in the `Volley` `Response.Listener`, receive the data and replace the `JSONArray` in the adapter by calling the above method with the new `JSONArray`.